# Appropriate "wishes" for pregnancy

Tags: phrase-requests, greetings

What is the appropriate way to express your best wishes to a woman who is having a baby?

(This is for a colleague, if there are different ways depending on different contexts please explain those, too).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A usual phrase to say is お体を大事にしてください (take care of yourself).

Another common phrase is 元気な赤ちゃんを産んでください (I wish you to have a healthy baby born), but some people avoid this phrase because it sounds as if a baby with a congenital disease were undesirable or unacceptable.

Comment: Could you just rephrase it to convey that you wish for the best outcome that doesn't carry the implication you mentioned?  Something like `赤ちゃんが無事に産まれますように祈ります／願います`?

Comment: @istrasci: Hmm, I am not sure.  赤ちゃんが無事に産まれるように願っています sounds okay, but it sounds a little scary to me because it sounds somewhat like “Although it is 50-50 whether you will have a baby born safely or not, I hope it will turn out to be safe.”  It might be just me, though.